# 'add text if more than 5 links plus display:none; if there are more than 5' script?

Tags: html

I have my codes like so:

```
.keywords a {
font-style:italic;}

.keywords a:nth-of-type(n+5) {
display:none}

<div class="keywords">{Keywords}</div>
```

The keywords are a-links and will be added automatically.

(it's possible to add as many keywords as you want to, though only the first five will be shown, this doesn't happen in this code itself though

e.g. [all of these can be seen as different articles on the page, each one has this div='keywords']

k1

k1, k2, k3

k1, k2, k3, k4, k5

_

if there are more than 5 keywords:

k1, k2, k3, k4, k5[, k6, k7] - these two won't be visible

how i want it to be (also 7 keywords):

k1, k2, k3, k4, k5[, k6, k7] more - k6 and k7 are again hidden, but the 'more' link is added)

I now want to add a 'more'-link as in 'if there are more than 5 keywords, then add a 'more'', but I don't know how to do this. Is there a script needed?

Comment: I think a script is needed for the "more" links case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?
https://jsfiddle.net/cd4aa8a0/1/

So i included a little bit of js and added another class to your css

```
.keywords:nth-child(n+6) a {
    display: none;   
}
```

JS

```
 $(".show").on('click', function(){
        $(".keywords:nth-child(n+6) a").toggle();
    });
```